# ReduceByKey CountByKey not working in Spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark

I'm new to spark and I have an assignment where I'm trying to provide an output that has the top two department names with most employee IDs from a csv. Here's the code I have so for this portion thusfar:

```
emp2 = emp1.map(lambda row : row.split(","))
emp_kv = emp2.map(lambda row : (row[8],1))
emp.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y).take(10)
```

However when I execute I get an error (I get a similar error when I do AggretageByKey as well so I'm a little lost):

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 91.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.0 in stage 91.0 (TID 215, localhost, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: `emp` on the last line be `emp_kv`. Also, most of the stacktrace is missing so it's impossible to see where the error occurs.

Comment: if csv then you can also use dataframe API to achieve the same

Comment: please add the command you used to read the csv file

Comment: please provide your csv input data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try the dataframe APIs. Dataframe is an abstraction over traditional RDDs which has schema, and contains a lot of implicit optimizations (using Catalyst optimizer and Tungsten execution engine).

## To load the data, use the below command:

`df = spark
    .read 
    .format("csv") 
    .option("header", "true") 
    .option("inferSchema", "true") 
    .option("path", "/path/to/dataset/") 
    .load()`

## Apply group by and aggregates

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df1 = df.groupBy("dept_name").agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))
```

## Sort them in descending order

```
df2 = df1.select("dept_name", "cnt").sort(desc("cnt")).limit(2)
```

## Print the results

```
df2.show()
```

Please let me know if it helps.